# how make objects counter via prototype?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script, which creates 3 objects. The constructor has a local variable `mushroomsCount`:

```
Mushroom = function(num) {
  var mushroomsCount = 0;

  this.id = num;
  this.Create();
}

Mushroom.prototype.Create = function() {
  this.mushroomsCount++;
}

Mushroom.prototype.Display = function() {
  console.log('mushromms count total is: ' + Mushroom.mushroomsCount);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var mushroom = [];
  mushroom[0] = new Mushroom(0);
  mushroom[1] = new Mushroom(1);
  mushroom[2] = new Mushroom(2);

  mushroom[2].Display();  // first way 
  Mushroom.Display();     // second way

});
```

after creating the objects, I try to display the number of the objects at `Mushroom.prototype.Display()`, but I'm getting `undefined`.

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrGppR?editors=001)

Comment: There's no relationship between variables and object properties.  Your `var mushroomsCount` is totally different memory from the `this.mushroomsCount` and the `Mushroom.mushroomsCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a property on `Mushroom` itselft (like you already had, but not had accessed).

```js
function Mushroom(num) {
    this.id = num;
    this.create();
}
Mushroom.mushroomCount = 0; // this is public!
Mushroom.prototype.create = function () {
    Mushroom.mushroomCount++;
}

Mushroom.prototype.display = function () {
    document.write('mushromms count total is: ' + Mushroom.mushroomCount + '<br>');
}

var mushroom = [];
mushroom[0] = new Mushroom(0);
mushroom[1] = new Mushroom(1);
mushroom[2] = new Mushroom(2);
mushroom[0].display();
mushroom[1].display();
mushroom[2].display();
```

Or use a closure with an IIFE:

```js
var Mushroom = function () {
    var mushroomCount = 0;
    var f = function (num) {
        this.id = num;
        this.create();
    };
    f.prototype.create = function () { mushroomCount++; }
    f.prototype.display = function () { document.write('mushromms count total is: ' + mushroomCount + '<br>'); }
    return f;
}();

var mushroom = [new Mushroom(0), new Mushroom(1), new Mushroom(2)];
mushroom[0].display(); 
mushroom[1].display(); 
mushroom[2].display();
```

Comment: It's a common practice to wrap IIFEs in brackets so it's easier to tell they're an IIFE from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Simple count instances of Mushroom 'class':

```
function Mushroom(num) {
    this.id = num;
    Mushroom.count++;
}
Mushroom.count = 0;
Mushroom.prototype.Display = function () {
    document.write('mushromms count total is: ' + Mushroom.count + '<br>');
}

var mushroom = [];
mushroom[0] = new Mushroom(0);
mushroom[1] = new Mushroom(1);
mushroom[2] = new Mushroom(2);
mushroom[2].Display();
```